# Regex Python concatenate lines if some text is found the line below

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
import re
output = open("teste-out.txt","w")
input = open("teste.txt")

for line in input:
    output.write(re.sub(r"\n\r03110", r"|03110", line))

input.close()
output.close()
```

Why this code isn´t working, anyone can help me fix it? I wanna read from a txt and if the line starts with `03110` I wanna merge only this line with the previous line and add `|` before the merge
I´ve tried `\n03110` `\r03110` and other options, but none is working. In notepad++ I can do this using `\R++03110` and replace with `|03110` using regular expressions, but I wanna a python solution to optimize the job.

Input

```
01000|0107160
02000|1446
03100|01|316,00
03110|||316,00|0|0|7|
03100|29|135,00
03110|||135,00|0|0|0|
99999|83
00000|00350235201512001|01071603100090489
02000|4720,905|1967,05|0
03100|31|705,26
03100|32|6073,00
03110|||6073,00|0|0|0,00|8
99999|23
```

Output

```
01000|0107160
02000|1446
03100|01|316,00|03110|||316,00|0|0|7|
03100|29|135,00|03110|||135,00|0|0|0|
99999|83
00000|00350235201512001|01071603100090489
02000|4720,905|1967,05|0
03100|31|705,26
03100|32|6073,00|03110|||6073,00|0|0|0,00|8
99999|23
```

I´m using python at windows.

Comment: could you please provide an example of input and the corresponding wished output?

Comment: `for line in input:` reads the file line by line. Your regex contains `\n\r` that matches LFCR symbols that makes the regex fail, as the LF line endings are not present in the `line`. Use `output.write(re.sub(r"^03110", r"|03110", line))` is you need to add `|` at the start of a line that starts with `03110`, or just use `if line.startswith('03110'): output.write(r"|{}".format(line))`

Comment: @Tryph I added an input and an output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I think I didn´t make myself clear enough, so I added a input and output as Tryph suggested.

Comment: Ok, anyway, you may append the lines without a line ending, and only add the line ending if the line does not start with `03110`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd EDIT: sorry - I guess I didn't read carefully enough...
Well, to merge lines with regards to the beginning of the *second* line is also possible, but perhaps not as beautifully clean:

```
with open('teste.txt') as fin, open('teste-out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(next(fin)[:-1])
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('03110'):
            fout.write(f'|{line[:-1]}')
        else:
            fout.write(f'\n{line[:-1]}')
    fout.write('\n')
```

---

EDIT: solution working with files:

```
with open('teste.txt') as fin, open('teste-out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('03100'):
            fout.write(line[:-1] + '|' + next(fin))
        else:
            fout.write(line)
```

---

Just for the case of interest - this is no `re` job imho:

```
s_in = '''01000|0107160
02000|1446
03100|01|316,00
03110|||316,00|0|0|7|
03100|29|135,00
03110|||135,00|0|0|0|
99999|83
00000|00350235201512001|01071603100090489'''

from io import StringIO

with StringIO(s_in) as fin:
    for line in fin:
        if line.startswith('03100'):
            print(line[:-1] + '|' + next(fin), end='')
        else:
            print(line, end='')
```

results in requested

```
01000|0107160
02000|1446
03100|01|316,00|03110|||316,00|0|0|7|
03100|29|135,00|03110|||135,00|0|0|0|
99999|83
00000|00350235201512001|01071603100090489
```

Comment: can you post a solution using "with open" so I can load my txt? Thanks! I´m very new at python

Comment: I need a regex solution with this command-like (r"\n\r03110", r"|03110") I need to merge the lines only if 03110 is at the start of the line below. So I need to search for the 03110 and not 03100. Don´t know if I made myself clear enough.

Comment: Sorry. Know I saw your edit. Can you make it works, so I search for 03110 and merge to the line above? I will edit my input and output to make myself clear

Answer (score 0):

For those who like `sed`, this is a very short solution (not that efficient, though, as it reads all lines before printing anything):

```sh
< input_file sed '$!N;s/\n03110/03110/g'
```

The following `sed` script is a more efficient solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
:h
N
s/\n03110/|03110/
t h
h
s/\n.*//
p
g
D
```

For the casual reader who really likes `sed` like I do, here's a short explanation:

- the 4 lines from `:h` to `t h` are essentially a "do-while" loop in which we append a new line to the pattern space (`N`), and we keep doing so (`t h` is a "goto"), as long as the substitution command (`s`) is successful in changing the embedded newline `\n` to a `|`;
- as soon as the `s` command is unsuccessful, we "save" the multiline pattern space copying it into the hold space (`h`), safely delete the `\n` and whatever is after it (`s/\n.*//`), and finally print the what remains (`p`), which is the lines that we've been successfully joining;
- it's now time to get back the last line we appended which did not start by `03110`: we get (`g`) the multiline back from the hold space, delete `\n` together with whatever precedes it and go to the top without printing (`D`).
- we are back to the top of the script with a line which is not printed yet, just like we started.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a python solution. Is there way to use it at python?